TinyMCE renders an extra widget
I use django-tinymce to render TinyMCE widgets in my forms. If updated to the latest version 6.8.3 (2024-02-08), I have two widgets on the same form field instead of one.
This is the Django template:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% load i18n %}{% load static %}

{% block title %}

...

{% endblock %}

{% block head %}{{ form.media }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<div id="create">
    <form id="cascade" class="mt-3" method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}{{ field }}{% else %}
        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ field.label }}:</label>
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <div class="form-text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <div id="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="invalid-feedback">{{ field.errors }}</div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action">{% translate "Submit" %}</button>
    </form>    
</div>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}

This is how the form field content using TinyMCE is actually rendered:
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="id_content" class="form-label">Содержимое:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control tinymce" cols="40" data-mce-conf="{&quot;theme&quot;: &quot;silver&quot;, &quot;height&quot;: 500, &quot;menubar&quot;: false, &quot;plugins&quot;: &quot;autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,preview,hr,searchreplace,code,media,table,paste,help,wordcount&quot;, &quot;contextmenu&quot;: &quot;paste | link image table&quot;, &quot;toolbar&quot;: &quot;bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr charmap | table | link image media | removeformat | code | help&quot;, &quot;paste_as_text&quot;: true, &quot;language&quot;: &quot;ru&quot;, &quot;directionality&quot;: &quot;ltr&quot;, &quot;strict_loading_mode&quot;: 1, &quot;selector&quot;: &quot;#id_content&quot;}" id="id_content" name="content" rows="10" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
    <div role="application" class="tox tox-tinymce" aria-disabled="false" style="visibility: hidden; height: 500px;"><div class="tox-editor-container"><div data-alloy-vertical-dir="toptobottom" class="tox-editor-header"><div role="group" class="tox-toolbar-overlord" aria-disabled="false"><div role="group" class="tox-toolbar__primary"><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Жирный шрифт" title="Жирный шрифт" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M7.8 19c-.3 0-.5 0-.6-.2l-.2-.5V5.7c0-.2 0-.4.2-.5l.6-.2h5c1.5 0 2.7.3 3.5 1 .7.6 1.1 1.4 1.1 2.5a3 3 0 0 1-.6 1.9c-.4.6-1 1-1.6 1.2.4.1.9.3 1.3.6s.8.7 1 1.2c.4.4.5 1 .5 1.6 0 1.3-.4 2.3-1.3 3-.8.7-2.1 1-3.8 1H7.8Zm5-8.3c.6 0 1.2-.1 1.6-.5.4-.3.6-.7.6-1.3 0-1.1-.8-1.7-2.3-1.7H9.3v3.5h3.4Zm.5 6c.7 0 1.3-.1 1.7-.4.4-.4.6-.9.6-1.5s-.2-1-.7-1.4c-.4-.3-1-.4-2-.4H9.4v3.8h4Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Курсив" title="Курсив" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="m16.7 4.7-.1.9h-.3c-.6 0-1 0-1.4.3-.3.3-.4.6-.5 1.1l-2.1 9.8v.6c0 .5.4.8 1.4.8h.2l-.2.8H8l.2-.8h.2c1.1 0 1.8-.5 2-1.5l2-9.8.1-.5c0-.6-.4-.8-1.4-.8h-.3l.2-.9h5.8Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Подчеркивание" title="Подчеркивание" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M16 5c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v5.5a4 4 0 0 1-.4 1.8l-1 1.4a5.3 5.3 0 0 1-5.5 1 5 5 0 0 1-1.6-1c-.5-.4-.8-.9-1.1-1.4a4 4 0 0 1-.4-1.8V6c0-.6.4-1 1-1s1 .4 1 1v5.5c0 .3 0 .6.2 1l.6.7a3.3 3.3 0 0 0 2.2.8 3.4 3.4 0 0 0 2.2-.8c.3-.2.4-.5.6-.8l.2-.9V6c0-.6.4-1 1-1ZM8 17h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Зачеркивание" title="Зачеркивание" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><g fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M15.6 8.5c-.5-.7-1-1.1-1.3-1.3-.6-.4-1.3-.6-2-.6-2.7 0-2.8 1.7-2.8 2.1 0 1.6 1.8 2 3.2 2.3 4.4.9 4.6 2.8 4.6 3.9 0 1.4-.7 4.1-5 4.1A6.2 6.2 0 0 1 7 16.4l1.5-1.1c.4.6 1.6 2 3.7 2 1.6 0 2.5-.4 3-1.2.4-.8.3-2-.8-2.6-.7-.4-1.6-.7-2.9-1-1-.2-3.9-.8-3.9-3.6C7.6 6 10.3 5 12.4 5c2.9 0 4.2 1.6 4.7 2.4l-1.5 1.1Z"></path><path d="M5 11h14a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></g></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Маркированный список" title="Маркированный список" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M11 5h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0 6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0 6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2ZM4.5 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Zm0 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Zm0 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Нумерованный список" title="Нумерованный список" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M10 17h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0-6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0-6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 1 1 0-2ZM6 4v3.5c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V5h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H6Zm-1 8.8.2.2h1.3c.3 0 .5.2.5.5s-.2.5-.5.5H4.9a1 1 0 0 1-.9-1V13c0-.4.3-.8.6-1l1.2-.4.2-.3a.2.2 0 0 0-.2-.2H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h1.6c.5 0 .9.4.9 1v.1c0 .4-.3.8-.6 1l-1.2.4-.2.3ZM7 17v2c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.2c.2 0 .3-.1.3-.3 0-.2-.1-.3-.3-.3H4.4a.4.4 0 1 1 0-.8h1.3c.2 0 .3-.1.3-.3 0-.2-.1-.3-.3-.3H4.5a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1H6c.6 0 1 .4 1 1Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Блок цитирования" title="Блок цитирования" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M7.5 17h.9c.4 0 .7-.2.9-.6L11 13V8c0-.6-.4-1-1-1H6a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v4c0 .6.4 1 1 1h2l-1.3 2.7a1 1 0 0 0 .8 1.3Zm8 0h.9c.4 0 .7-.2.9-.6L19 13V8c0-.6-.4-1-1-1h-4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v4c0 .6.4 1 1 1h2l-1.3 2.7a1 1 0 0 0 .8 1.3Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Горизонтальная линия" title="Горизонтальная линия" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M4 11h16v2H4z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Специальный символ" title="Специальный символ" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M15 18h4l1-2v4h-6v-3.3l1.4-1a6 6 0 0 0 1.8-2.9 6.3 6.3 0 0 0-.1-4.1 5.8 5.8 0 0 0-3-3.2c-.6-.3-1.3-.5-2.1-.5a5.1 5.1 0 0 0-3.9 1.8 6.3 6.3 0 0 0-1.3 6 6.2 6.2 0 0 0 1.8 3l1.4.9V20H4v-4l1 2h4v-.5l-2-1L5.4 15A6.5 6.5 0 0 1 4 11c0-1 .2-1.9.6-2.7A7 7 0 0 1 6.3 6C7.1 5.4 8 5 9 4.5c1-.3 2-.5 3.1-.5a8.8 8.8 0 0 1 5.7 2 7 7 0 0 1 1.7 2.3 6 6 0 0 1 .2 4.8c-.2.7-.6 1.3-1 1.9a7.6 7.6 0 0 1-3.6 2.5v.5Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button title="Таблица" aria-label="Таблица" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="tox-tbtn tox-tbtn--select" aria-expanded="false" style="user-select: none; width: 48px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M19 4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14ZM5 14v4h6v-4H5Zm14 0h-6v4h6v-4Zm0-6h-6v4h6V8ZM5 12h6V8H5v4Z"></path></svg></span><div class="tox-tbtn__select-chevron"><svg width="10" height="10" focusable="false"><path d="M8.7 2.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1 0 .4.4.4.9 0 1.2L5.7 7.8c-.3.3-.9.3-1.2 0L.2 3.4a.8.8 0 0 1 0-1.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0L5 6l3.7-3.8Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></div></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Вставить/редактировать ссылку" title="Вставить/редактировать ссылку" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M6.2 12.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-2 2a2 2 0 1 0 2.6 2.8l4.8-4.8a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.4 1 1 0 1 1 1.4-1.3 2.9 2.9 0 0 1 0 4L9.6 20a3.9 3.9 0 0 1-5.5-5.5l2-2Zm11.6-.6a1 1 0 0 1-1.4-1.4l2-2a2 2 0 1 0-2.6-2.8L11 10.3a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.4A1 1 0 1 1 9.6 13a2.9 2.9 0 0 1 0-4L14.4 4a3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.5 5.5l-2 2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Вставить/изменить изображение" title="Вставить/изменить изображение" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="m5 15.7 3.3-3.2c.3-.3.7-.3 1 0L12 15l4.1-4c.3-.4.8-.4 1 0l2 1.9V5H5v10.7ZM5 18V19h3l2.8-2.9-2-2L5 17.9Zm14-3-2.5-2.4-6.4 6.5H19v-4ZM4 3h16c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v16c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4c0-.6.4-1 1-1Zm6 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Вставить/редактировать мультимедиа" title="Вставить/редактировать мультимедиа" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M4 3h16c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v16c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4c0-.6.4-1 1-1Zm1 2v14h14V5H5Zm4.8 2.6 5.6 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .8l-5.6 4A.5.5 0 0 1 9 16V8a.5.5 0 0 1 .8-.4Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button></div><div role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Reveal or hide additional toolbar items" title="Reveal or hide additional toolbar items" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-tbtn" aria-expanded="false"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M6 10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm12 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-6 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button></div></div></div><div class="tox-anchorbar"></div></div><div class="tox-sidebar-wrap"><div class="tox-edit-area"><iframe id="id_content_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Поле форматированного текста" class="tox-edit-area__iframe" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; /></head><body id=&quot;tinymce&quot; class=&quot;mce-content-body &quot; data-id=&quot;id_content&quot; aria-label=&quot;Поле форматированного текста. Нажмите ALT-0, чтобы открыть справку.&quot;><br></body></html>"></iframe></div><div role="presentation" class="tox-sidebar"><div data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-sidebar__slider tox-sidebar--sliding-closed" style="width: 0px;"><div class="tox-sidebar__pane-container"></div></div></div></div><div class="tox-bottom-anchorbar"></div><div class="tox-statusbar"><div class="tox-statusbar__text-container tox-statusbar__text-container-3-cols tox-statusbar__text-container--flex-start"><div role="navigation" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-statusbar__path" aria-disabled="false"><div data-index="0" aria-level="1" role="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-statusbar__path-item" aria-disabled="false">p</div></div><div class="tox-statusbar__help-text">Press Alt+0 for help</div><div class="tox-statusbar__right-container"><button type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-statusbar__wordcount">0 слов</button><span class="tox-statusbar__branding"><a href="https://www.tiny.cloud/powered-by-tiny?utm_campaign=poweredby&amp;utm_source=tiny&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_content=v6" rel="noopener" target="_blank" aria-label="Под управлением Tiny" tabindex="-1"><svg width="50px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 50 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.143 0c2.608.015 5.186 2.178 5.186 5.331 0 0 .077 3.812-.084 4.87-.361 2.41-2.164 4.074-4.65 4.496-1.453.284-2.523.49-3.212.623-.373.071-.634.122-.785.152-.184.038-.997.145-1.35.145-2.732 0-5.21-2.04-5.248-5.33 0 0 0-3.514.03-4.442.093-2.4 1.758-4.342 4.926-4.963 0 0 3.875-.752 4.036-.782.368-.07.775-.1 1.15-.1Zm1.826 2.8L5.83 3.989v2.393l-2.455.475v5.968l6.137-1.189V9.243l2.456-.476V2.8ZM5.83 6.382l3.682-.713v3.574l-3.682.713V6.382Zm27.173-1.64-.084-1.066h-2.226v9.132h2.456V7.743c-.008-1.151.998-2.064 2.149-2.072 1.15-.008 1.987.92 1.995 2.072v5.065h2.455V7.359c-.015-2.18-1.657-3.929-3.837-3.913a3.993 3.993 0 0 0-2.908 1.296Zm-6.3-4.266L29.16 0v2.387l-2.456.475V.476Zm0 3.2v9.132h2.456V3.676h-2.456Zm18.179 11.787L49.11 3.676H46.58l-1.612 4.527-.46 1.382-.384-1.382-1.611-4.527H39.98l3.3 9.132L42.15 16l2.732-.537ZM22.867 9.738c0 .752.568 1.075.921 1.075.353 0 .668-.047.998-.154l.537 1.765c-.23.154-.92.537-2.225.537-1.305 0-2.655-.997-2.686-2.686a136.877 136.877 0 0 1 0-4.374H18.8V3.676h1.612v-1.98l2.455-.476v2.456h2.302V5.9h-2.302v3.837Z"></path></svg></a></span></div></div><div title="Изменить размер" aria-label="Press the Up and Down arrow keys to resize the editor." data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-statusbar__resize-handle"><svg width="10" height="10" focusable="false"><g fill-rule="nonzero"><path d="M8.1 1.1A.5.5 0 1 1 9 2l-7 7A.5.5 0 1 1 1 8l7-7ZM8.1 5.1A.5.5 0 1 1 9 6l-3 3A.5.5 0 1 1 5 8l3-3Z"></path></g></svg></div></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="tox-view-wrap" style="display: none;"><div class="tox-view-wrap__slot-container"></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="tox-throbber" style="display: none;"></div></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_content"><div id="id_content" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;"></div>
    <!--An extra widget-->
    <div role="application" class="tox tox-tinymce" aria-disabled="false" style="visibility: hidden; height: 500px;"><div class="tox-editor-container"><div data-alloy-vertical-dir="toptobottom" class="tox-editor-header"><div role="group" class="tox-toolbar-overlord" aria-disabled="false"><div role="group" class="tox-toolbar__primary"><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Жирный шрифт" title="Жирный шрифт" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M7.8 19c-.3 0-.5 0-.6-.2l-.2-.5V5.7c0-.2 0-.4.2-.5l.6-.2h5c1.5 0 2.7.3 3.5 1 .7.6 1.1 1.4 1.1 2.5a3 3 0 0 1-.6 1.9c-.4.6-1 1-1.6 1.2.4.1.9.3 1.3.6s.8.7 1 1.2c.4.4.5 1 .5 1.6 0 1.3-.4 2.3-1.3 3-.8.7-2.1 1-3.8 1H7.8Zm5-8.3c.6 0 1.2-.1 1.6-.5.4-.3.6-.7.6-1.3 0-1.1-.8-1.7-2.3-1.7H9.3v3.5h3.4Zm.5 6c.7 0 1.3-.1 1.7-.4.4-.4.6-.9.6-1.5s-.2-1-.7-1.4c-.4-.3-1-.4-2-.4H9.4v3.8h4Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Курсив" title="Курсив" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="m16.7 4.7-.1.9h-.3c-.6 0-1 0-1.4.3-.3.3-.4.6-.5 1.1l-2.1 9.8v.6c0 .5.4.8 1.4.8h.2l-.2.8H8l.2-.8h.2c1.1 0 1.8-.5 2-1.5l2-9.8.1-.5c0-.6-.4-.8-1.4-.8h-.3l.2-.9h5.8Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Подчеркивание" title="Подчеркивание" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M16 5c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v5.5a4 4 0 0 1-.4 1.8l-1 1.4a5.3 5.3 0 0 1-5.5 1 5 5 0 0 1-1.6-1c-.5-.4-.8-.9-1.1-1.4a4 4 0 0 1-.4-1.8V6c0-.6.4-1 1-1s1 .4 1 1v5.5c0 .3 0 .6.2 1l.6.7a3.3 3.3 0 0 0 2.2.8 3.4 3.4 0 0 0 2.2-.8c.3-.2.4-.5.6-.8l.2-.9V6c0-.6.4-1 1-1ZM8 17h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Зачеркивание" title="Зачеркивание" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><g fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M15.6 8.5c-.5-.7-1-1.1-1.3-1.3-.6-.4-1.3-.6-2-.6-2.7 0-2.8 1.7-2.8 2.1 0 1.6 1.8 2 3.2 2.3 4.4.9 4.6 2.8 4.6 3.9 0 1.4-.7 4.1-5 4.1A6.2 6.2 0 0 1 7 16.4l1.5-1.1c.4.6 1.6 2 3.7 2 1.6 0 2.5-.4 3-1.2.4-.8.3-2-.8-2.6-.7-.4-1.6-.7-2.9-1-1-.2-3.9-.8-3.9-3.6C7.6 6 10.3 5 12.4 5c2.9 0 4.2 1.6 4.7 2.4l-1.5 1.1Z"></path><path d="M5 11h14a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></g></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Маркированный список" title="Маркированный список" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M11 5h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0 6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0 6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2ZM4.5 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Zm0 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Zm0 6c0-.4.1-.8.4-1 .3-.4.7-.5 1.1-.5.4 0 .8.1 1 .4.4.3.5.7.5 1.1 0 .4-.1.8-.4 1-.3.4-.7.5-1.1.5-.4 0-.8-.1-1-.4-.4-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.1Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Нумерованный список" title="Нумерованный список" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M10 17h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0-6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Zm0-6h8c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1h-8a1 1 0 1 1 0-2ZM6 4v3.5c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V5h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H6Zm-1 8.8.2.2h1.3c.3 0 .5.2.5.5s-.2.5-.5.5H4.9a1 1 0 0 1-.9-1V13c0-.4.3-.8.6-1l1.2-.4.2-.3a.2.2 0 0 0-.2-.2H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h1.6c.5 0 .9.4.9 1v.1c0 .4-.3.8-.6 1l-1.2.4-.2.3ZM7 17v2c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.2c.2 0 .3-.1.3-.3 0-.2-.1-.3-.3-.3H4.4a.4.4 0 1 1 0-.8h1.3c.2 0 .3-.1.3-.3 0-.2-.1-.3-.3-.3H4.5a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1H6c.6 0 1 .4 1 1Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Блок цитирования" title="Блок цитирования" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M7.5 17h.9c.4 0 .7-.2.9-.6L11 13V8c0-.6-.4-1-1-1H6a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v4c0 .6.4 1 1 1h2l-1.3 2.7a1 1 0 0 0 .8 1.3Zm8 0h.9c.4 0 .7-.2.9-.6L19 13V8c0-.6-.4-1-1-1h-4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v4c0 .6.4 1 1 1h2l-1.3 2.7a1 1 0 0 0 .8 1.3Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Горизонтальная линия" title="Горизонтальная линия" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M4 11h16v2H4z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Специальный символ" title="Специальный символ" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M15 18h4l1-2v4h-6v-3.3l1.4-1a6 6 0 0 0 1.8-2.9 6.3 6.3 0 0 0-.1-4.1 5.8 5.8 0 0 0-3-3.2c-.6-.3-1.3-.5-2.1-.5a5.1 5.1 0 0 0-3.9 1.8 6.3 6.3 0 0 0-1.3 6 6.2 6.2 0 0 0 1.8 3l1.4.9V20H4v-4l1 2h4v-.5l-2-1L5.4 15A6.5 6.5 0 0 1 4 11c0-1 .2-1.9.6-2.7A7 7 0 0 1 6.3 6C7.1 5.4 8 5 9 4.5c1-.3 2-.5 3.1-.5a8.8 8.8 0 0 1 5.7 2 7 7 0 0 1 1.7 2.3 6 6 0 0 1 .2 4.8c-.2.7-.6 1.3-1 1.9a7.6 7.6 0 0 1-3.6 2.5v.5Z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button title="Таблица" aria-label="Таблица" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="tox-tbtn tox-tbtn--select" aria-expanded="false" style="user-select: none; width: 48px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M19 4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14ZM5 14v4h6v-4H5Zm14 0h-6v4h6v-4Zm0-6h-6v4h6V8ZM5 12h6V8H5v4Z"></path></svg></span><div class="tox-tbtn__select-chevron"><svg width="10" height="10" focusable="false"><path d="M8.7 2.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1 0 .4.4.4.9 0 1.2L5.7 7.8c-.3.3-.9.3-1.2 0L.2 3.4a.8.8 0 0 1 0-1.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0L5 6l3.7-3.8Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></div></button></div><div title="" role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Вставить/редактировать ссылку" title="Вставить/редактировать ссылку" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M6.2 12.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-2 2a2 2 0 1 0 2.6 2.8l4.8-4.8a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.4 1 1 0 1 1 1.4-1.3 2.9 2.9 0 0 1 0 4L9.6 20a3.9 3.9 0 0 1-5.5-5.5l2-2Zm11.6-.6a1 1 0 0 1-1.4-1.4l2-2a2 2 0 1 0-2.6-2.8L11 10.3a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.4A1 1 0 1 1 9.6 13a2.9 2.9 0 0 1 0-4L14.4 4a3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.5 5.5l-2 2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Вставить/изменить изображение" title="Вставить/изменить изображение" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="m5 15.7 3.3-3.2c.3-.3.7-.3 1 0L12 15l4.1-4c.3-.4.8-.4 1 0l2 1.9V5H5v10.7ZM5 18V19h3l2.8-2.9-2-2L5 17.9Zm14-3-2.5-2.4-6.4 6.5H19v-4ZM4 3h16c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v16c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4c0-.6.4-1 1-1Zm6 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button><button aria-label="Вставить/редактировать мультимедиа" title="Вставить/редактировать мультимедиа" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 34px;"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M4 3h16c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v16c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4c0-.6.4-1 1-1Zm1 2v14h14V5H5Zm4.8 2.6 5.6 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .8l-5.6 4A.5.5 0 0 1 9 16V8a.5.5 0 0 1 .8-.4Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button></div><div role="toolbar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-toolbar__group"><button aria-label="Reveal or hide additional toolbar items" title="Reveal or hide additional toolbar items" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-tbtn" aria-expanded="false"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false"><path d="M6 10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm12 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-6 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2c0 1.1.9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2-2Z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button></div></div></div><div class="tox-anchorbar"></div></div><div class="tox-sidebar-wrap"><div class="tox-edit-area"><iframe id="id_content_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Поле форматированного текста" class="tox-edit-area__iframe" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; /></head><body id=&quot;tinymce&quot; class=&quot;mce-content-body &quot; data-id=&quot;id_content&quot; aria-label=&quot;Поле форматированного текста. Нажмите ALT-0, чтобы открыть справку.&quot;><br></body></html>"></iframe></div><div role="presentation" class="tox-sidebar"><div data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-sidebar__slider tox-sidebar--sliding-closed" style="width: 0px;"><div class="tox-sidebar__pane-container"></div></div></div></div><div class="tox-bottom-anchorbar"></div><div class="tox-statusbar"><div class="tox-statusbar__text-container tox-statusbar__text-container-3-cols tox-statusbar__text-container--flex-start"><div role="navigation" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-statusbar__path" aria-disabled="false"><div data-index="0" aria-level="1" role="button" tabindex="-1" class="tox-statusbar__path-item" aria-disabled="false">p</div></div><div class="tox-statusbar__help-text">Press Alt+0 for help</div><div class="tox-statusbar__right-container"><button type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-statusbar__wordcount">0 слов</button><span class="tox-statusbar__branding"><a href="https://www.tiny.cloud/powered-by-tiny?utm_campaign=poweredby&amp;utm_source=tiny&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_content=v6" rel="noopener" target="_blank" aria-label="Под управлением Tiny" tabindex="-1"><svg width="50px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 50 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.143 0c2.608.015 5.186 2.178 5.186 5.331 0 0 .077 3.812-.084 4.87-.361 2.41-2.164 4.074-4.65 4.496-1.453.284-2.523.49-3.212.623-.373.071-.634.122-.785.152-.184.038-.997.145-1.35.145-2.732 0-5.21-2.04-5.248-5.33 0 0 0-3.514.03-4.442.093-2.4 1.758-4.342 4.926-4.963 0 0 3.875-.752 4.036-.782.368-.07.775-.1 1.15-.1Zm1.826 2.8L5.83 3.989v2.393l-2.455.475v5.968l6.137-1.189V9.243l2.456-.476V2.8ZM5.83 6.382l3.682-.713v3.574l-3.682.713V6.382Zm27.173-1.64-.084-1.066h-2.226v9.132h2.456V7.743c-.008-1.151.998-2.064 2.149-2.072 1.15-.008 1.987.92 1.995 2.072v5.065h2.455V7.359c-.015-2.18-1.657-3.929-3.837-3.913a3.993 3.993 0 0 0-2.908 1.296Zm-6.3-4.266L29.16 0v2.387l-2.456.475V.476Zm0 3.2v9.132h2.456V3.676h-2.456Zm18.179 11.787L49.11 3.676H46.58l-1.612 4.527-.46 1.382-.384-1.382-1.611-4.527H39.98l3.3 9.132L42.15 16l2.732-.537ZM22.867 9.738c0 .752.568 1.075.921 1.075.353 0 .668-.047.998-.154l.537 1.765c-.23.154-.92.537-2.225.537-1.305 0-2.655-.997-2.686-2.686a136.877 136.877 0 0 1 0-4.374H18.8V3.676h1.612v-1.98l2.455-.476v2.456h2.302V5.9h-2.302v3.837Z"></path></svg></a></span></div></div><div title="Изменить размер" aria-label="Press the Up and Down arrow keys to resize the editor." data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-statusbar__resize-handle"><svg width="10" height="10" focusable="false"><g fill-rule="nonzero"><path d="M8.1 1.1A.5.5 0 1 1 9 2l-7 7A.5.5 0 1 1 1 8l7-7ZM8.1 5.1A.5.5 0 1 1 9 6l-3 3A.5.5 0 1 1 5 8l3-3Z"></path></g></svg></div></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="tox-view-wrap" style="display: none;"><div class="tox-view-wrap__slot-container"></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="tox-throbber" style="display: none;"></div></div>
</div>

In settings.py, I have this configuration:
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "theme": "silver",
    "height": 500,
    "menubar": False,
    "plugins": "autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,preview,hr,searchreplace,code,media,table,paste,help,wordcount",
    "contextmenu": "paste | link image table",
    "toolbar": "bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr charmap | table | link image media | removeformat | code | help",
    'paste_as_text': True,
}

